# Apply "OR" condition in Order Collection in Magento 2.4.3

Tags: magento2, orders, collection, magento2.4.3, datepicker

How to apply "OR" Condition on Order Collection ??

**Example:-**

I want to filter order collection on these 4 date on order collection.

```
November 27, 2020
November 29, 2019
November 23, 2018
November 24, 2017
```

I am applying the filter at a time On 1 date like this:-

```
$from = date("2020-11-27 00:00:00");
$to = date("2020-11-27 23:59:59");

$orderCollection = $orderFactory->create()
    ->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array('gteq' => $from))
    ->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array('lteq' => $to));
```

**How can I filter 4 dates in order collection ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, you need something like this:

```
$collection->getSelect()
        ->where('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%Y-%m-%d") = ?', '2020-11-23')
        ->orWhere('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%Y-%m-%d") = ?', '2020-11-24')
        ->orWhere('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%Y-%m-%d") = ?', '2020-11-27')
        ->orWhere('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%Y-%m-%d") = ?', '2020-11-29');
```

Comment: Thank you for your response let me check and let you know...+1

Comment: Thank you it's working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

When you are passing array value in the `addFieldToFilter` function arguments, the system will do the OR condition.

If you look at the function definition of `addFieldToFilter` function in [`\Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb::addFieldToFilter`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4.3/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Data/Collection/AbstractDb.php#L388-L404)

```
public function addFieldToFilter($field, $condition = null)
{
    if (is_array($field)) {
        $conditions = [];
        foreach ($field as $key => $value) {
            $conditions[] = $this->_translateCondition($value, isset($condition[$key]) ? $condition[$key] : null);
        }

        $resultCondition = '(' . implode(') ' . \Magento\Framework\DB\Select::SQL_OR . ' (', $conditions) . ')';
    } else {
        $resultCondition = $this->_translateCondition($field, $condition);
    }

    $this->_select->where($resultCondition, null, Select::TYPE_CONDITION);

    return $this;
}
```

So in your case you can try to do the following

```
$orderCollection = $orderFactory->create()
    ->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter(
           ['created_at', 'created_at'], 
           [
              ['from' => '2020-11-27 00:00:00', 'to' => '2020-11-27 23:59:59'],
              ['from' => '2019-11-29 00:00:00', 'to' => '2019-11-29 23:59:59'],
           ]
      );
```

Comment: Thank you for your response let me check and let you know...+1